# Optimize query containing too many inner join and rows

Tags: optimization, sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO ##TempStaffT
FROM Staff HF 
WHERE  HF.[businessline_id]='T'
AND HF.[offices_id] IN (SELECT * FROM ##TempParamOffice)
AND HF.[specialism_id]IN (SELECT * FROM ##TempParamSpecialism)
AND HF.[onetouch]IN (SELECT * FROM ##TempParamConsultant)

 SET @sql4 = N'

INSERT INTO ##TempFees(' + @columns1 + ',CALF_AN ,BusinessName)
SELECT distinct ' + @columns2 + ',p.CALF_AN ,CB.[TempBusinessName] as BusinessName
   FROM 
     dbo.WTEFAC EF 
  inner JOIN  dbo.WTFAC F ON EF.EFAC_NUM = F.EFAC_NUM 
  inner JOIN  dbo.WTFACINFO BS ON F.FAC_NUM = BS.FAC_NUM 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTLFAC LF ON F.FAC_NUM = LF.FAC_NUM 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTRUBVARIANTEFAC WRU ON LF.RINT_ID = WRU.RINT_ID 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTACUMFAC WTA ON WRU.RUV_ID = WTA.RUV_ID 
  inner JOIN ##CUM_CODEHT WTA1 ON WTA.CUM_ID = WTA1.CUM_ID 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTVTAT TAT ON BS.TIE_ID = TAT.TIE_ID AND BS.RFAN_ID = TAT.RFAN_ID AND BS.PER_ID = TAT.PER_ID AND BS.CNT_ID = TAT.CNT_ID
  inner JOIN dbo.PYCONTRAT CC ON TAT.PER_ID = CC.PER_ID AND TAT.CNT_ID = CC.CNT_ID 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTMISS M ON CC.PER_ID = M.PER_ID AND CC.CNT_ID = M.CNT_ID 
  inner JOIN dbo.WTCNTI COT1 ON M.PER_ID = COT1.PER_ID AND M.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID
  inner JOIN dbo.WTQUAEU Q ON COT1.TIE_ID = Q.TIE_ID AND COT1.QEU_CDE = Q.QEU_CDE
  inner JOIN dbo.WTSCCT C ON CC.RGPCNT_ID = C.RGPCNT_ID AND CC.PER_ID = C.PER_ID AND CC.CNT_ID = C.CNT_ID --AND''SECT3'' = C.STTQ_COD 
  INNER JOIN ##TempStaffT HF ON C.VAPO_CODE = HF.onetouch  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
  inner JOIN 
##TempA AS p  ON p.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID  inner JOIN 
 ##TempB AS p1  ON p1.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID
  CROSS JOIN [dbo].[CustBusinessTable] CB
WHERE  CB.[TempBusinessName]=''Pure Temp Fees''

GROUP BY p.CALF_AN,CB.[TempBusinessName]
'
;
PRINT @sql4;
```

My problem is that the query above took 20 min to be executed because `##TempStaffT` contains too many rows.  How can I optimize it? I use many temp tables but it seems to not be working.

Comment: You have a query, but you have not specified what it does **at all**. Please explain a bit about what your query does, and what all the cryptic names and aliases mean.

Comment: There are multiple uses of variables in this query, none of which are declared. This query will not run.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using *global* temporary tables as opposed to just plain ol' temp tables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Code Review Stack Exchange advice**

It *really* helps if you explain, in plain English, what your code does or is supposed to do. As it stands, nobody has any idea what your code is supposed to do, and the best we can do is guess. With that in mind...

---

**Nitpicks**

Your aliases make no sense. Your table names are cryptic enough (you probably can't change that) but to alias `WTFAC` as `F` certainly doesn't help. `WTFACINFO` as `BS` to me only suggests this: **WTF BS**.

---

Your capitalization of SQL keywords is all over the place. Make it all caps, or all lower case, or whatever. Just stick to one style and be consistent.

---

Your indentations are not very helpful; in fact I find them confusing at best. Use indentations that are meaningful to make the code easier to sift through. For example, this:

```
inner JOIN dbo.WTVTAT TAT ON BS.TIE_ID = TAT.TIE_ID AND BS.RFAN_ID = TAT.RFAN_ID AND BS.PER_ID = TAT.PER_ID AND BS.CNT_ID = TAT.CNT_ID
```

Why not instead write:

```
INNER JOIN dbo.WTVTAT TAT 
    ON BS.TIE_ID = TAT.TIE_ID 
    AND BS.RFAN_ID = TAT.RFAN_ID 
    AND BS.PER_ID = TAT.PER_ID 
    AND BS.CNT_ID = TAT.CNT_ID
```

---

**END YOUR SQL STATEMENTS PLEASE**

Not using the delimiter `;` throughout your query makes it much more difficult to understand the logic of your code. Use `;` and even `GO` if need be. MS SQL Server is forgiving on syntax errors (try PostgreSQL for fun), that doesn't mean you shouldn't follow good practices of ending statements properly.

---

## **`SELECT *`**

```
SELECT * 
INTO ##TempStaffT
FROM Staff HF
```

[image]

Do you *really* need every column from this table? Perhaps you do, but more likely not. This could improve performance if you are more verbose about selecting exactly the columns you want and no more.
`SELECT *` makes the SQL engine query the information schema to get all the information about every column in the table, it can slow things down.

## **`CROSS JOIN`!?**

This:

```
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[CustBusinessTable] CB
```

My view is that, unless you *know* you need a `CROSS JOIN`, you don't need a cross join. They are insanely slow and that is likely why your query takes so long. If you indeed *know* you need the cartesian product of `[dbo].[CustBusinessTable]` and `##TempB` then I guess you're out of luck. But I have a feeling there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I can see what you are doing, unlike some others and I would suggest you approach performance problems in this way :

1) Lift out the SELECT statement and build it table by table.
2) Dress the SQL to make it readable for those that come after you.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM        dbo.WTEFAC                   EF 

INNER JOIN  dbo.WTFAC                    F 
    ON EF.EFAC_NUM = F.EFAC_NUM

INNER JOIN  dbo.WTFACINFO                BS 
    ON F.FAC_NUM = BS.FAC_NUM 

INNER JOIN  dbo.WTLFAC                   LF 
   ON F.FAC_NUM = LF.FAC_NUM 

etc.
```

3) If you have no need of OUTER JOINS, consider...

```
   SELECT ... 
   FROM        dbo.WTEFAC                   EF 
              ,dbo.WTFAC                    F 
              ,WTFACINFO                    BS 
   ...        
   WHERE EF.EFAC_NUM = F.EFAC_NUM
     AND  F.FAC_NUM  = BS.FAC_NUM 
   ....
  etc.
```

4) As you add tables, look for the performance degradation and address as required, This may mean DBA input, indexing, partitioning and the like. Reading an EXPLAIN for instance. The DISTINCT is a real worry, have you tried selecting count(*)  or the first 1000 rows to get an eyeball on the duplicates ? This is bread and butter stuff.

5) 20 mins does not seem so bad to me, what is that in dollars ? Does this load need to happen often ? There are event driven mirroring products out there that could queue the updates from the journal.

6) Whilst I cannot see your ERD or your rowcounts, you should be aware that smaller tables could be memory resident, and your buffering/prefetch tuning should be up to scratch.

Comment: You really shouldn't recommend ANSI style joins. They only make queries less readable than using the `JOIN` keyword.

Comment: I personally find the indentation style you are proposing insulting. Because it makes the query no more readable and there is no actual bemefit in using it. Additionally this is the first time I have ever seen SQL written in that manner. You are also not explicitly aliasing and 20 minutes are quite something... But the other half of your answer makes nice and valid points, so I will abstain from voting.

Comment: Wow, that style of indentation is horrible. I thought it must have been my phone, that's why I didn't comment on it earlier.

Comment: Actually this is just a recommendation, I may have overdone it, but when you start hitting 15 tables or more it becomes hard to locate them from the aliases. The indentation is not the point, the alignment of the join clauses and the aliases is.  All big shops do this. 20 mins is not a lot in my experience, it will depend upon the size of the data.

Comment: I actually kind of like having the aliases indented to the right, however it might get difficult to manage with varying table name length, which happens... always. I think your answer is mostly good, not a big fan of ANSI-89 join. You may find [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) interesting.

Comment: The indentation is a bit... much, but you've got some good points here. And 20 minutes really might not be that long depending on it's size and *purpose*. Sure, you can't let an end user sit for 20 minutes waiting for results, but a nightly ETL process would be fine.